# Jquery function expects string and gets json, handle data

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jquery function that expects a string as a response. However, under a very rare circumstance it will recieve a json encoded object. Thus I am using:

```
function is_json(str) {
    try {
        var o = JSON.parse(str);

        // Handle non-exception-throwing cases:
        // Neither JSON.parse(false) or JSON.parse(1234) throw errors, hence the type-checking,
        // but... JSON.parse(null) returns null, and typeof null === "object", 
        // so we must check for that, too. Thankfully, null is falsey, so this suffices:
        if (o && typeof o === "object") {
            return o;
        }
    } catch (e) {
    }

    return false;
}
```

to check if we are receiving a JSON response. Unfortunately, even if we are, the function is returning false. This was confirmed using developer panel.

Here is the script:

```
$('.create-viewer').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var table = $(this).attr('data-table');
    var url = '/neou_cms/ajax/table_render?id=' + id + '&table=' + table;
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (is_json(data)) {
            console.log('data_is_json');
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            data = obj.msg;
            // do something with data...
        }
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: data,
            title: $_lang.view_header,
            buttons: {
                success: {
                    label: $_lang.actions_ok,
                    className: 'btn-primary'
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My response has an `application/json` header confirmed with Chrome and is in the following format:

`{"status":"error","msg":"Some message here."}`

which validates according to JSONLint

Comment: why don't you return all of your responses as JSON? Easier to hadle and manipulate. Also it is good to have a single type response.

Comment: If the response has `Content-type: application/json`, jQuery will call `JSON.parse` itself, so `data` will contain the resulting object, not the JSON.

Comment: @Barmar so basically i should just check if i have an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify the datatype argument to `$.get`, it tries to deduce the type from the `Content-type` header. In your case, since it says `application/json`, jQuery automatically parses it for you, and `data` will be the parsed object. So you can simply do:

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
    if (typeof data == 'object') {
        data = data.msg;
    }
    ...
});
```